# What is the jargon or area of study for this type of code (non-compliant, non-conforming)?

Tags: javascript, computer-science, standards, anti-patterns, standards-compliance

What is the technical jargon for a module/library that's considered bad because it strays from or changes standard behavior (especially implicitly)?

For example, if I have `module.js` with the following contents...

```js
Object.assign = (x, y) => {
  // Do a deep copy instead...
}
```

...consumers of the module could end up confused when `Object.assign` doesn't work like usual.

Also, what's the area(s) of study that this falls under? I want to know what to search so I can read about it.

EDIT: Changed to a better example

Comment: That code just wouldn't work. You can't add a listener to the array-like node list that `querySelectorAll` returns. Maybe you need a better example.

Comment: that's totally OK if an app needs that behavior. i wouldn't consider that an anti-pattern. Also you should use `forEach()` here

Comment: @Andy oh, thanks for the heads up! Fixed

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I agree, but there are definitely talks about this subject in the industry. I just can't pinpoint the exact jargon, if any

Comment: @JoeBoris i believe it's related to SPA routing, when you override default navigation but allow to open `<a>` links in a new window

Comment: It leans into accessibility. My first thought would be you shouldn't be using anchors for this you should probably be using buttons. But without understanding the context of the rest of the code it's hard to say. @JoeBoris

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I meant the broader subject of compliant/conforming code. Another example is that people often complain that overwriting standard built-in methods like array.push is a bad idea. Just wondering if there's a word for that

Comment: I suspect that just comes under the umbrella term "bad practice" @JoeBoris

Comment: I'd call it "*overwriting builtins with non-conforming implementations*". I don't think there is single word for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called monkey patching.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Your example of the monkey patching is malicious and nobody should do that. Because it will break almost any code that uses `Object.assign`.

About this particular example you could do a variant:

```js
{
  let assign;
  [assign, Object.assign] = [Object.assign, function(dst, ...sources){
    if(sources.at(-1) === 'deep-copy'){
      return assign.call(Object, dst, ...sources.slice(0, -1).map(src => structuredClone(src)));
    }
    return assign.apply(Object, arguments);
  }]

}

const a = {};
const b = {prop:{test:true}};

Object.assign(a, b, 'deep-copy');

b.prop.test = false;

console.log(a);
```

`Object.assignDeepCopy()` looks better and safer and there's less typing, but unfortunately it will fail when JS would add the same method in the future (see below)...

So with this `Object.assign` case we don't have a 100% bulletproof solution unfortunately...

The best approach would be just:

```
Object.assign(a, structuredClone(b));
```

But in general the answer whether the monkey patching is bad is opiniated unfortunately.

I love monkey patching BUT:

- monkey patching in your project is OK
- you have to keep the default behavior, just add extra functionality
- if you deliver code for using by others (a framework, a module, a library) it's **NO**

**On the other hand**

Extending for example `Array.prototype` could be a bad idea:

- you add `Array.prototype.flat()` to flatten an array recursively before 2018-09-04.
- in 2018-09-04 Chrome 69 Released which adds the JS version of `flat`.
- you upgrade your dependencies which started using JS `flat`.
- your app breaks because you override the default behavior of the JS `flat` (1 level deep) and your dependencies stop working as expected.

Compared to monkey patching existing methods:

I believe JS follows the SOLID's open–closed principle so no behavior of existing functions would ever change.

So if you monkey patch `Array.prototype.find` for example to work with object filters like `arr.find({id: 1})` I think it will work forever unless you add some bad 3rd party code with monkey patching this method too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean anchor tags specifically. I meant the broader concept of compliant/conforming code. I'll update the question with a different example

Comment: I agree that monkey patching is libraries is almost always a bad idea, however there are very specific cases in which it can be useful, such as polyfills.

Comment: However adding extra functionality to existing standard objects is a very, very bad as well. Just look at [SmooshGate](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/smooshgate/)

Comment: @MichaelM. agree, but that's not pure monkey patching because it's not overriding existing methods but adding missing ones

Comment: @MichaelM. afaik JS follows open–closed principle so no behavior of existing function would change ever. so if you add for example `arr.find({id: 1})` it will work forever

Comment: Yes, but if you were to add extra functionality, like you said in your, to an object defined by the standard library, such as `Object.prototype` or `window.location`, a new feature may be released in the future with the same name as your monkey patch. This would cause a lot of problems for you and even more for anyone using your library.